# Javascript | Understanding security of callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need help to understand the security of callback functions. My case is, that I've a client and a server-side code, connected with socket.io. My client is sending a object using socket.io to the server and the callback has to answer if everything is fine. The server calls a method, and the method returns true or false. If true, server has to answer.

**My call from client:**

```
socket.emit('client.to.server', {id: objID}, () => {
    console.log('this is my callback')
})
```

**Serverside socket.io event:**

```
socket.on('client.to.server', (dataObject, callback = null) => {
    let result = this.doSomething(dataObject, socket)
    if (result === true && (typeof callback === 'function')) callback()
})
```

So, my question is: **Is this secure?** I mean, the client is sending a callback function to the server and the server calls this function server-side, what if somebody manipulates this function somehow to send me some dirt to the server? I hope I could explain what I mean.

I know I can replace this whole callback through simply emitting from server to client.
**But what is better?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the client is sending a callback function to the server

You are misunderstanding it. The callback function is *not* sent to the server at all. The flow actually looks like this:

```
             client                                     server
 client sends data to server
socket.emit('client.to.server')
                       pushes to fifo queue[0]
                    ----------------------->
                                                server triggers listener
                                              socket.on('client.to.server')
                                               server sends data to client
                       pushes to fifo queue[1]
                    <-----------------------
  client triggers callback
() => console.log('this is my callback')
```

Sockets are a *message-passing* mechanism. You can only pass serializable objects (binary data) through them.

Comment: The first part of the answer is good, but the last sentence seems unnecessary/irrelevant since JavaScript code is serializable.

Comment: @Paulpro I doubt a callback function is serializable since it contains way too many information such as scope.

Comment: A JavaScript function can easily be serialized. That doesn't mean its context or any other state is also necessarily serialized, although it certainly can be. The OP's callback in particular doesn't use any free variables except `console` so it would behave identically in other contexts where a similar `console` object is available.

Comment: Regardless, I think that sentence can add to the OP's confusion. I think the OP's confusion stems from the fact that they explicitly call `callback()` in the server, and `callback` seems to be a client-side function. They need some clarification that the `callback` they are calling on the server is not the client-side callback function they passed into socket.emit, but instead it's a function passed in by socket.io to handle sending the response data back to the client where the callback will really be called (implicitly by socket.io)

Comment: @Paulpro In theory, yes, every object can be serialized since they are represented in some form in the memory. But in general we consider callback functions as not serializable since it would not be useful and possibly dangerous.

Comment: Thank you @Paulpro. Derek what would you do isntead?

Comment: @bonblow What do you mean?

Comment: @bonblow To be clear, I upvoted this answer and think you should accept it if it helped you understand that the callback function is never sent to the server.

Comment: @bonblow Paulpro also brought out a good point where you should be aware that the `callback` variable the library passed is not the same as the function on the client side. Calling `callback` merely lets the library knows that you are trying to pass some data back, and a message will be delivered to the client.

Answer (score -2):

So what you are basically trying to do is remote procedure call and the way you are doing it is not at all safe. The easiest approach you can take is that you should define some pre-defined functions that are called when you receive some type of identifier. For eg, Your call from client can be:

**Call from client:**

```
socket.emit('client.to.server', 
  {id: objID}, 
  "LOG_DATA", 
  ["data to be logged"]
})
```

**Serverside socket.io event:**

```
function processType(type, params) {
  switch(type) {
    case LOG_DATA:
      console.log(params[0]); // u can also have predefined functions over here
    case ANOTHER_FUNCTION:
      anotherFunction(params[0], params[1]);
    default:
      doSomething(params);

  }
}
socket.on('client.to.server', (dataObject, type, params) => {
    let result = this.doSomething(dataObject, socket)
    if (result === true && type) processType(type, params)
})
```

If you really need to call a remote procedure from the client side then you should try to encrypt your data at the client side and then decrypt at the server side and then call the remote procedure.  This approach will be quite complicated as it will require some kind of key exchange mechanism. However, if you want I can explain it further as well.

Comment: This solution is not needed and the first sentence is wrong. There is nothing inherently unsafe about socket.io callbacks.